# setText does not work when I call it in another class

Tags: android

I am calling setText() for a number of TextViews in different activities, so I though I should define a function for this.
In my OnCreate method i am using the following code to call the function:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myAct);

    View inflatedView = (this.getLayoutInflater()).inflate(R.layout.activity_myAct, null);
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);

    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
    rf.OpenWithTitles(getApplicationContext(), inflatedView, is, "Titles", "Texts", this.getPackageName());
```

My OpenWithTitles function is as follows:

```
public void OpenWithTitles(Context context, View inflatedView, InputStream is, String title, String text, String packName){
    //Open text files with Titles on one line and one empty line before next Title.
    id = 0;
    boolean nextTitle = true;

    try {
        StringBuilder fileText = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if (nextTitle){
                id++;
                fileText.append(line);
                SetTextView(context, inflatedView, title, packName, fileText);
                nextTitle = false;
            }
            else if (line.length()==0) {           //Empty lines between titles
                fileText.setLength(fileText.length()-1);
                SetTextView(context, inflatedView, text, packName, fileText);
                nextTitle = true;
            }
            else {
                fileText.append(line);
                fileText.append('\n');
            }
        }
        SetTextView(context, inflatedView, text, packName, fileText);
        br.close();
   }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the SetTextView function is as follows:

```
public void SetTextView(Context context, View inflatedView, String idName, String packName, StringBuilder text){
    ((TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier(idName + id, "id", packName))).setText(text);
    text.setLength(0);
}
```

I have defined my android:id's correctly (dubble and tripple checked).
I have used Log.d to print and check the identifier returned in the SetTextView function and checked this versus the same value for that idName+id in R.java manually by opening the R.java file. I have also checked this by using ResourceName() of the value obtained.
I have checked the text (which is to be set) to see whether it contains correct text (which it does).
I have checked idName+id and compared these to the .xml file.
And it does not return any errors whatsoever, it runs and opens the activity, but the text does not show. (it does show text if I add android:text in the xml file).

Comment: Side note: naming conventions, use them.

Comment: The view you're inflating is never set to the activity content. You're setting this one `R.layout.activity_quran` and inflating and modifying another one `R.layout.activity_myAct`.

Comment: this is corrected in my question, but it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating a layout in this line:

```
View inflatedView = (this.getLayoutInflater()).inflate(R.layout.activity_myAct, null);
```

but you are not using it in your `Activity`. You are setting an XML file for your content here:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_quran);
```

You should probably pass your `Activity` in to your method, so change this:

```
rf.OpenWithTitles(getApplicationContext(), inflatedView, is, "Titles", "Texts", this.getPackageName());
```

to this:

```
rf.OpenWithTitles(getApplicationContext(), this, is, "Titles", "Texts", this.getPackageName());
```